# how to access env variables in runtime elixir (localhost) windows

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I am using Windows machine where i have elixir project. I have env.bat file where all the environment variables are set. While running the elixir project in local, environment variables are not getting retrieved.

I have tried changing env.bat to .env and having runtime.exs but that is for prod

**env.bat file**  `set ENABLE_XXX=true`
**in config.exs**  `config :app, enable: System.get_env("ENABLE_XXX")`
**in module**`host = Application.get_env(:app, :enable)`
**start server**`mix phx.server`

when access the API call it is showing as nil. how to access enviornment variables in runtime on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.get_env("ENABLE_XXX")` from the module, or set it up up in [`config/runtime.exs`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#module-config-runtime-exs).

Comment: could you elaborate more about usage of  runtime.exs. Still i am getting nil  with System,get_env(ENABLE_XXX) from the module

Answer (score 0):

with env.bat:

```
call env.bat
```

and

```
mix phx.server
```

did the trick.